# ngClick does not work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

My ngClick call is not working. It throws no error nor do the function I've declared in $scope. Everuthing else seems to work just fine. My code is as follows:

ng-app:

```
 var app = angular.module('dilemas', [
    'ngRoute',
    'dilemas.controllers',
  'dilemas.services'
]);
```

The controller:

```
_module.controller('controllerName', ['api', '$scope', function(api, $scope) {

    $scope.gotoNext = function(){ console.log("I'm here ;)") };

}]);
```

The view:

```
<div id="myID" ng-controller="controllerName">

    <div class="ct-full">
        <div class="ct-center">

            <h1 class="pergunta">Question?</h1>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div ng-include="'include/footer.html'"></div>

</div>
```

And finally the footer include:

```
<div id="footer" class="ct-full">
    <div class="ct-full">
        <div class="ct-center">
            <div class="btn btnNext spriteBase" ng-click="gotoNext()">Next ></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, just didn`t mention here because everything works fine. I'll edit the question anyways.

Comment: Works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/3Dc5AXj86ORK9EzAu3o3?p=preview. Create a plunkr reproducing the error. Check your console for errors.

Comment: No errors thrown in the console. It worked for me in the plunkr, but still doesn't work on my project. Should I say all the controllers are required using browserify's require function.

Answer (score -1):

You can't call `gotoNext` method because `ng-include` creates a new child scope.

You could use `$parent.gotoNext()` in `ng-click`.

```
<div class="btn btnNext spriteBase" ng-click="$parent.gotoNext()">Next ></div>
```

Comment: The scope created by `ng-include` is a child scope with prototypical inheritance, so there is no need to reference `$parent`.